# Kafka Key access on Ingress of a Python Flink Stateful function

Tags: python, apache-flink, remote-execution, flink-statefun

I've been looking at Flink Stateful Functions. It looks super promising - except for one thing - and I hope I'm just missing it.

For the life of me, can't see a way to access the kafka key from a kafka ingress in Python. In Java, I see I could use the deserialiser and effectively pack it into the decoded `message` object. But I can't find an alternative.
In our case, the key has valuable info, that does not exist in the value.

Anyone come across this - or have I just missed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I'd like to mention is that the builtin Kafka ingress for remote functions, requires that the key can be interpreted as a UTF-8 string.
If this is indeed your case, then you can simply obtain it via:

```
def example(context, message):
  key = context.address.id 
  ... 
  print(key) # utf8 string
```

If this is not the case, then unfortunately at this point, you would have to use the embedded SDK, to extract the key and the value before forwarding the message to a remote function.

Comment: Perfect - thanks. Yip - I just missed this